# React Context Provider not setting value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-context

I am trying to get started with React context hooks and I seem to be having an issue I dont understand.

I have defined a user context that is simply a string that says "hello user" as such:

```
import { useContext, createContext } from "react"

export const UserContext = createContext<string | null>(null)

export interface IAuth {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Auth: React.FC<IAuth> = (props) => {

  return(
    <UserContext.Provider value={"hello user"}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Auth
```

Then I am attempting to access is like this:

```
const Dash: NextPage<dashPageProps> = (props) => {

  const contextMsg = useContext(UserContext)

  const submitForm = () => {
    console.log("logout")
  }

  return (
    <Auth>
    <div className="w-screen">
      <div className='text-xl'>
        Dashboard
      </div>
      <h1>{contextMsg}</h1>
      <button className='bg-gray-400 border-2 border-gray-600 w-fit mt-5' onClick={submitForm} >Log out</button>
    </div>
    </Auth>
  )
}

export default Dash
```

But nothing is being printed out even though I have set a value when using `UserContext.Provider`. It will have a value if I specify one when creating the context but not when I set it through the provider.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The provider (`<Auth>`) needs to be higher up the component tree than the consumer (`<Dash>`). You have it the other way around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Auth` is called within the component but you call `useContext` before `Auth` usage which means your Context API has not been initialized yet

In the usual components, you can initialize them with a component wrapper like

```
<Context.Provider>
  <YourComponent/> // you call `useContext` in `YourComponent`
</Context.Provider>
```

But in Next.js, especially, under a page-level component, it's not a good way to construct multiple Context APIs due to clean code concerns

I'd suggest you should move your `Auth` to `_app.tsx` like below that would help you initialize your Context API before all page-level components' renderings

```
export default function MyApp(props: AppProps) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Auth>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Auth>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Dash.tsx

```
const Dash: NextPage<dashPageProps> = (props) => {

  const contextMsg = useContext(UserContext)

  const submitForm = () => {
    console.log("logout")
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-screen">
      <div className='text-xl'>
        Dashboard
      </div>
      <h1>{contextMsg}</h1>
      <button className='bg-gray-400 border-2 border-gray-600 w-fit mt-5' onClick={submitForm} >Log out</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dash
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `useContext` outside its `Provider`.

You will need to move your `Auth` component up a level so that it surrounds `Dash` in order to make use of `const contextMsg = useContext(UserContext)`

In the end your React Component Tree should look like this:

```
<Auth>
  <Dash />
</Auth>
```